# How would I create back, forward, and refresh buttons for a UIWebView programmatically?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I currently have a webview created but I do not want to use interface builder to create the back, forward, and refresh buttons. How would I create these buttons programmatically? I know how to create regular buttons with code, but as for webView delegate buttons, I am lost and have not been able to find many resources on it.

Answer (score 7):

From the [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation:

> If you allow the user to move back and forward through the webpage history, then you can use the [goBack](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/goBack) and [goForward](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/goForward) methods as actions for buttons. Use the [canGoBack](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/canGoBack) and [canGoForward](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/canGoForward) properties to disable the buttons when the user can’t move in a direction.

Setting up the buttons would then use [`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:) (as pointed out by [Sven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639411/how-would-i-create-back-forward-and-refresh-buttons-for-a-uiwebview-programmati/3639456#3639456)):

```
[myBackButton addTarget:myWebView
                 action:@selector(goBack)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

If you want to get fancy and enable/disable the buttons based on the `canGoBack` and `canGoForward` properties, you will have to add some KVO notifications to your `UIController`.

Comment: Just to share a good tutorial: http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2013/11/17/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-revisited-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the target and action for the buttons using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` to your web view.

Answer (score 0):

To enable/disable Back or Forward button instead of using `KVO`, we can use the following "`hack`"

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

    if ([webView canGoBack])
        [backbutton setEnabled:YES];
    else
        [backbutton setEnabled:NO];

    if ([webView canGoForward])
        [fwdbutton setEnabled:YES];
    else
        [fwdbutton setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to enable or disable buttons is:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   [backButton setEnabled:webView.canGoBack];
   [fwdButton setEnabled:webView.canGoForward];
}
```